# JS try again if error

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

if function returns error, further code is no longer executing. I need to retry this function until success. How can I do it?

```
... // API request...

function(error, something) {
    if (!error) {
    something = true;
    // Etc...
    }
    else {
        // Code to try again.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  do {
    // do your stuff here
  }while(error)
```

For tour case you can do it like this :

```
function(error, something) {
    do {
        // do your stuff here
      }while(error)
}
```

To do what you want until the error become false

Or you can use while

```
    function(error, something) {
        if(!error){
            // this code is executed once
         }
            while(error){
                // do your stuff here
              }
        }
```

It will test the error before executing the first time

For more example [take a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp)

For the last comment you can do it like this (without loop) :

```
function Test(error, something) {
        if(!error){
            // your code that you want to execute it once
        }
        else {
            // do stuff
            Test(error, something); // re-call the function to test the if
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. Can you explain?

Comment: So If error is false, it will execute do { } until success?

Comment: This will always execute the code at least one time, else you can use while() loop i add it to the answer take a look

Comment: I dont want to use "// do your stuff here" until error is false. So what I should use?

Comment: In your question you said that you want to retry untill success so I give you this loop which is used until the condition is true, else you can use the if condition if tou don't want to loop

Comment: Take a look now i edited my answer, sorry I don't understand you before

Comment: I need this. Function > if error is true, try until its false > execute code once > ...

Comment: Im testing your code, I dont know if it works until error is going to be true. To make everything clear: Now, if error is true, it will try until its false and execute " // this code is executed once" once?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But can you tell me what your third code does? If error is true it will try again until its false, and execute my code once or many times?

Comment: No it just test once if error is false else it will loop to execute many times the code between {} of while

Comment: I tried your last code. Im getting this error: function(error, tradedata); ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Yes normal, you need to give a name to your function like my last edit take a look

Answer (score 6):

I prefer having a function calling it self so you have more freedom

```
function repeat() {
  repeat()
}
```

Then you can all kind of tings. Your example would be

```
const repeat = () => {
    // Your code
    if(error) {
        repeat()
    }
}
```

If you only run it once, then make a self executing function.

```
(function repeat() {
    // Your code
    if(error) {
        repeat()
    }
})()
```

Because we use a function calling it self we can use setTimeout

```
(function repeat() {
    // Your code
    if(error) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            repeat()
        }, 100)
    }
})()
```

This makes it possible for the code to have a little break insted of running none stop.

Comment: wouldn't this eventually run into a stack overflow?